# How does form value caching work in browsers?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, caching, browser

I've read somewhere in a documentation that most browsers don't update DOM as form values change, because frequent DOM manipulation need heavy computing performance. Instead, they create a cache of form values to register form manipulation, and only update the DOM when a the form is submitted.

Do browsers really work this way? Is there an extensive documentation about this behavior?

Comment: This is pretty easy to test. What have you tried?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. DOM elements have _properties_ and _attributes_. If you change an _attribute_ e.g. the `value=""` then the DOM is changed. But the current value of a `form` element is stored in the _property_ `value` and this is the one that is changed when the user types something e.g. into an `input` field. If the attribute changes the css rules needs to be rechecked if some don't apply anymore or some others will apply now.

Comment: canon: Checking Chrome's DOM Inspector, it seems that all input field values remain unchanged. However, in Firefox's debugger, everything seems to update instantly as I type anything in any input field.

Comment: t.niese: That seems correct, but in this case, why does Firefox's DOM inspector display updated attributes as well?

Comment: @kdani I need to check, but if you open http://jsfiddle.net/4nPnz/  in current firefox or chrome and type `bar` or click on `prop-change` the color is not changing to green. But if you click on `attr-change` it turns green because the attribute changes. Additionally if you reload and type e.g. `test` into it and then press `attr-change` you see that it will turn green but `test` will still be the current value.

Comment: @kdani I don't see any changes in the DOM inspector. I which ff version did you see that behavior?

Comment: @t.niese: your test case behaves exactly the same here. Actually I have been testing this on a rather complex website, which was not a good idea. Possibly some event handlers were updating the attributes as well. Actually I think, this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

DOM elements have *properties* and *attributes*.

If you change an attribute e.g. the `value=""` then the DOM is changed.
But the current `value` of a form element is stored in the *property* `value` and this is the one that is changed when the user types something e.g. into an input field.

If the attribute changes the css rules needs to be rechecked if some don't apply anymore or some others will apply now.

**Here a little example:**

*CSS*

```
[value='foo'] {
    color: red;
}

[value='bar'] {
    color: green;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<input id="text-element" type="text" value="foo"><br>

<a href="#" id="prop-change">prop-change</a>
<a href="#" id="attr-change">attr-change</a>
```

*JS*

```
document.getElementById("attr-change").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("text-element").setAttribute("value","bar");
    return false;
};

document.getElementById("prop-change").onclick  = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("text-element").value = "bar";
    return false;
};
```

**[Live Demo (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/4nPnz/2/)**

If you try this in current FireFox or Chrome and type `bar` or click on `prop-change` the color is not changing to *green*.

But if you click on `attr-change` it turns *green* because the attribute changes.

Additionally if you reload and type e.g. `test` into it and then press `attr-change` you see that it will turn *green* but `test` will still be the current value.