# JS Cannot pass value to parent's text input element [weird behaviour]

Tags: javascript, html

**popuptest.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="formid" >
    <input type="text" id="textinput" value="empty value" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddeninput" value="empty value" />
    <button type="button" onclick="window.open('popup.xhtml', 'Select Reference','status,width=400,height=400');" >Open PopUp</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="
    opener.document.getElementById('textinput').value = 'text value from child pop up !';
    opener.document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value = 'hidden value from child pop up !';
    window.close();
">Put values to parent</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Open popuptext.xhtml -> press open popup button -> press Put values to parent
What I observe in parent window:

[image: seems that value was passed to parent text input]
seems that value was passed to parent text input

But on the other hand what I see in the Chrome debug (F12):

[image: omg! text input is empty! and value was passed to hidden input(as expected)]

omg! text input is empty! and value was passed to hidden input(as expected)

Chrome version: 29.0.1547.76 m
Same on Firefox 24.0
Is there any explanation of such behaviour? Is it a bug?
I need to pass value to the text input and then submit form but in this case the form doesn't contain my value.

Comment: So is it just the debugging tools which are showing it empty? What actually gets submitted when you submit the form, or access it with Javascript DOM functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed value (*property*) and the value in the dom (*attribute*) are two different things.

That attribute set in the DOM is like the default value of the `input` element. If no value  is stored in the *property* `value` then the one of the DOM attribute is displayed.
If a value is stored in the *property* `value` then this one is displayed instead of the one stored in the attribute, but as you observed the dom attribute remains untouched.

If you store `null` in the property `value` then *default* value is displayed again.

So your observed behavior is is correct.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917922/how-does-form-value-caching-work-in-browsers/18918578#18918578) an answer to another question that shows one effect of the difference between *property* and *attribute*

Comment: I understood that property and attribute are different.  
What I need to do to fix it? Can I do anything?
Why for hidden type of input it works?

Comment: @user1320115 just moved it form comment to answer to add more details, is there anything still unclear?

Comment: e.g. when I type something in the text input - DOM isn't changed, right? But when I submit - then attribute value = param value and form is sent to server, right?

Comment: @user1320115 exactly. if you type something into the field, only the property is changed. When the form is submitted it sends the _property_ if it was set and otherwise the _attribute_.